# Play! 2: How to Detect Library Version

Tags: playframework-2.0

Is there a fast (possibly command line) way to find out which version of a certain library is being used by a Play! Framework project without having to look at the JARs or googling?

I'm on Windows 7/Java 7/Play 2.2.1 if that's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `dependencies` or `show allDependencies` from the play console good enough?

Comment: It's a standard sbt task, you'd have to wrap ```show allDependencies```with quotes if you want to call it from the command line with the play command, so ```play "show allDependencies"```

Comment: Ah, yes. Silly me. :D